# Osacript for Tmux sessions doesn't work after Brew Update

Tags: tmux, osascript

My [spotify script](https://github.com/andy4thehuynh/dotfiles/blob/master/applescripts/current_track.sh) does not execute since I ran `brew update`. Now my current Spotify or iTunes song doesn't render on my Tmux status bar.

I tried outputting a string and the script gives me text back so I do not think it's Osascript. I'm on Yosemite 10.10.2 and using iTerm. Any idea why this suddenly stopped working?

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the call to `osascript` with [reattach-to-user-namespace](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard). There are some [known problems](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174779/unable-to-run-display-notification-using-osascript-in-a-tmux-session) with evaluating certain AppleScript command inside tmux.

You can install the wrapper through Homebrew and use it like this:

```
reattach-to-user-namespace osascript -e 'display notification "Hello, world"'
```

Without reattach-to-user-namespace that command will not display a notification in tmux 2.0.